# How to check if a windows user has read & write privileges to a certain folder using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, permissions, electron

I am trying to validate a directory path. All I need is to throw an error in case if folder is not accessible at all or user has no write permissions. I need to run the validation synchronously.

The problem occurs only ONLY on windows machines.
It seems that `fs.accessSync(path, fs.constants.R_OK | fs.constants.W_OK)` works differently for posix and win32 systems. On windows it will never throw an error if the directory exists, even if the user does not have required permissions to write to that folder. On macOS it throws an error just fine.

```
fs.accessSync(pathToADirectoryWithWriteRestrictions, fs.constants.W_OK);
// undefined on windows. Indicating that path is accessible as per docs;
// throws an error on mac
```

Expected: fs.accessSync to throw EPERM error, saying that user has no needed permissions to write to this directory.

The other option I've tried - getting directory stats with `fs.statSync`, converting it's `mode` property to octal numeral system to get unix-like permission numbers.

I've found out that the mode property does not change even if I modify permissions on that folder. It shows 16822 all the time, which is basically a read&write permissions.

```
// getting directory stats
const directoryStats = fs.statSync(pathToDirectory);
const statsMode = directoryStats.mode; // 16822

// converting directory stats mode to the Octal numeral system
// to get unix-like permission numbers

const unixLikePermissions = '0' + (directoryStats.mode & parseInt('777', 8)).toString(8);
console.log(unixLikePermissions) // 0666
```

Is there any other way to check if the user has all needed rights to operate with a certain directory using node.js? Am I missing something?